# Execute activator command on Jenkins

Tags: jakarta-ee, jenkins, sbt, typesafe-activator

I am trying to build a play Java project through jenkins and to achieve this, I have installed sbt plugin to clean and compile. Its works perfectly fine but when i use ./activator dist command in execute shell. It fails my build with the following errors:

> 1. Could not retrieve activator-launcher 1.2.2
> 2. Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries

Answer (score 0):

Activator is an extended version of SBT, so you're not going to have access to Activator commands by installing an SBT plugin.

I think you have three options:

1. If you are allowed, you can install the [Play Framework Plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Play+Framework+Plugin) which looks to have all the activator commands in it.
2. Commit the activator.bash file with your source so you have access to it (but please don't do this).
3. Don't use activator dist. Use the [sbt-assembly-plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) instead.